# Get row from the table based on from and to parameters sql

Tags: sql

Hello I've the following table.

[image]

I gave this query

```
SELECT * FROM Charges where AmountFrom < 50 and AmountTo > 50
```

It gave the first record.

When I gave the query

```
SELECT * FROM Charges where AmountFrom < 5000 and AmountTo > 5000
```

My Amount is to validate 5000 dollars and get the charge value for 5000

It should give me 1st record too right??.

Comment: With the second query, how can you get the first row?

Comment: @Wanderer I'm just asking if my Amount is 5000 dollars, how can I get the charge value?

Comment: On a side note: With this data model you have gaps. You won't find charge values for prices 0.90, 5000.50, etc. One way to get around this is to have only either AmountFrom or AmountTo. Another is to have AmountFromExcluding instead of AmountFrom: 0-5000, 5000-10000, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do like this

```
SELECT * FROM Charges where AmountFrom <= 5000 and AmountTo >= 5000
```

than you will get first record. as value of AmountTo of first record is 5000.

if you do `AmountTo >5000` it will give you record which value is greater than 5000 not record which value 5000.

or try like

```
SELECT * FROM Charges where AmountFrom < 5000 and AmountTo > 4999
```

Comment: Pranay, so what is the general query for any case? if I supply the Amount value, it should return me the charge value

Comment: @Yakhoob - you want to pass only one prameter to query ?? if yes than make use of >= for AmountTo

Comment: For a general answer you should change `AmountFrom < 5000` to `AmountFrom <= 5000`, too, because otherwise you'll have the same problem again when looking for the value 5001.

Comment: @PranayRana it should be select * from charges where amountfrom <= 5000 and amountto >= 5000

Answer (score 1):

To get the first record when your amount is `5000`, you should use `greater than & equal to operator ">="` , You can use simply like this :

```
SELECT * FROM Charges where AmountFrom < 5000 and AmountTo >= 5000
```

If you are using sql server, then you can achieve the result by using a variable for your amount like this :

```
declare @Amount money
set @Amount = 5000

SELECT ChargeValues FROM Charges where AmountFrom <= @Amount and AmountTo >= @Amount
```

Answer (score 1):

With

```
SELECT * FROM Charges where AmountFrom < 5000 and AmountTo > 5000
```

you are looking for entries that start with a value smaller than 5000 and end with a value greater than this. No such record exists. You'd rather want to include the value:

```
select * from charges where amountfrom <= 5000 and amountto >= 5000
```

or simply

```
select * from charges where 5000 between amountfrom and amountto
```

(`BETWEEN` includes the from and to values in the search.)